# Where can I find FDA approval SPL drug data?

Tags: openfda

I am doing a study on approval label drug data for prescription drugs and want to get a a large dataset of the approval label for a drug. I will be then comparing this with later versions of the drug label data. Is there a database where this is easily accessible? I have been using dailymed but it seems to just keep a random collection of older versions.

The only option I am aware of at this point is manually downloading every single PDF from https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/daf/ which seems like a mammoth task.

Is there an easier way here?